# How does the voting and reputation system work?

Tags: support, reputation, voting, new-users

I am new to this site and am trying to work out how to vote for other people's comments and answers. There doesn't seem to be a button for this.

Can someone please explain or provide a link to the relevant help file?

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Comment: And here's [a meta.SE FAQ link about voting on comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17364/254929).

Answer (score 5):

Voting up is a privilege only awarded to those who have 15 reputation in order to avoid people from gaming the system:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up

Voting down, however, is only awarded at 125 reputation because it requires a greater understanding of the site and what is considered "not useful":

https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

You can see all privileges here:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

As you build reputation, these privileges will begin to come and you will get alerts as you gain them, so it just takes patience.

Reputation can be earned in the following ways:

1. Suggested Edits
2. Up Votes on Answers
3. Accepted Answers
4. Accepting an Answer to Your Own Question
5. Receiving a Bounty
6. Up Votes on Questions

and can be lost in the following ways:

1. Down Votes on Answers
2. Down Votes on Questions
3. Awarding a Bounty
4. A Reputation-Building Event that has been Revoked for Any Reason

Also, reputation can not be earned on meta sites.

Comment: Note that you can accept a question on your own questions, no matter how much reputation you have.