# Is reputation a measure of intelligence?

Tags: discussion, reputation, new-users

Life is hard on Stack Overflow for us, the under 1000 reputation guys! It seems impossible to earn this level of reputation, a level which appears to indicate unusual intelligence or ability.

This leads me to question the nature of reputation:

1. Is 1k+ reputation a matter of points accumulated in time or a matter of genius?
2. Are reputation points secretly *buyable*?

Comment: "Any 1k+ user is by definition cleverer than you" - not really! Maybe they joined earlier than you, or they are more patient in answering beginners questions, or they have more free time available, or ...

Comment: Clearly not; I'm living proof.

Comment: I have 10k rep and I'm still an idiot.

Comment: I have 200k rep and I'm still an idiot.

Comment: You will soon (hopefully) be above 1k in rep. and this question, with its interesting title, will become an insult, by you, to the rest of us... ;)

Comment: There must be some posts that you've deleted because I'm seeing what @josilber eluded to. If you have deleted posts and you want to ask about why those specific posts have been downvoted, then you should undelete those posts and link the them specifically. FWIW, I have 6k+ rep and I'm still an idiot.

Comment: I have 56 rep and I'm a Cardassian.

Comment: Omg, we are surrounded by idiots!

Comment: How exactly wasn't this seeking input?  There's an insightful answer already.

Comment: Thank you @josilber and Nooble and all :) ... Wow, I was just curious and -22 in a few minutes. That's really cool! :)

Comment: I have 2.3k rep and I am the smartest person on StackOverflow. If anyone even remotely doubts this, I'll have you know I got a 190 on a free online IQ test. I also took a free online class from MIT and got a cool little certificate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the voting and reputation system work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252814/839601) and [Is it legitimate to “buy” Stack Overflow reputation?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270795/839601)

Comment: Which dictionary did you get that definition from?

Comment: Yes, I'm smart and you're dumb.  it's self evident.  No wonder you had to ask this question.

Comment: “Everybody is a genius. But if you judge a fish by its ability to climb a tree, it will live its whole life believing that it is stupid.”

Comment: Thank you @TinyGiant - But no deleted posts with downvotes :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

All reputation is really a measure of is how much you have contributed to the site (and the value of said contributions, as judged by your peers). To get to a level of 100K is largely a matter of time, especially since there is a rep cap of 200 per day (does not include accepts and bounties).

That said, you have to be knowledgeable in the area you are posting in order to gain reputation, so it is an *indication* that you know what you are talking about if you have a high number. There are plenty of competent programmers under 1000 rep (all of us were once!) and probably a few incompetent ones above (although I suspect they are few).

And no, you can't buy rep.

Comment: Thanks: It's clearly explained! I was just curious. Nothing else.

Comment: I have seen a number of incompetent/lazy 1k+ers, and quite frankly nothing makes me hit downvote harder

Comment: @nkjt was the `1k+ers`deliberate or bordering on the serendipitous?

Comment: @BillWoodger unintentional but now I've seen it I wish I'd done it on purpose.

Answer (score 4):

I finally understood: Stack Overflow is just like social life itself: keep calm and you'll be rewarded!

When I first joined SO, it was because I saw a question and I did want to give an answer. As time goes, and I see more and more pages with members with so high reputation, I thought: *"there are so many members who already know the same answer I'm about to give, and they came here years before I did; their reputation will always stay unreachable;"* and I went frustrated.

Today I know that this is the wrong way to go with SO. I realized that:

- **Stack Overflow is not a place for competitions like battles/wars** where we should hear: *"I am the most intelligent,"* and just after that: *"No, not you - it's me the one most intelligent!"* and so on...
  SO should be a place where one has to present himself as a valuable person.
- **Reputation is definitely far from being intelligence**: As soon as you've *-one day-* answered a single question that made someone happy, then you are a valuable person! No matter whether you have 10 reputation or not.
- **`qq|$SO_Reputation| =~ /ThankYouSoMuch/`**: Reputation is some kind of *"Thank You"*, some kind of **side effect**; the more you have, the more you appear to be open to others.

I now think that the following should be among the *"things that should certainly be considered when you're a member of SO"* :

- **Keep calm!** This is not an arena for fights in order for the crowd to see the best one. Just answer anywhere when you're deeply convinced that you can.
- **You should not answer a question because you want to earn reputation**; IMHO the most useless answers come from that idea that *"I have to earn reputation therefore I have to answer many questions."*
- **Your reputation is just perfect**, even if it's tiny. You've answered a question one day that solved someone's problem. Then you are valuable. Period. Whether you did it 1000 times or only 1 time, you still are valuable. Your reputation is just right as it is.
- **You shouldn't buy reputation**, even if one day that becomes possible.

And most importantly, I did not answer that question with a view to earn reputation.

Answer (score -1):

Reputation on SE does not necessarily reflect intelligence. But if a user has been on this site for more than 5 years, have tried really hard & still can't get over 1000 reps, it does reflect the lacking of the said intelligence in such a user.

Comment: Could be we're just lazy.

Comment: Wiser words have occasionally, but rarely, been spoken.

Comment: @TheForestAndTheTrees you probably skipped the "have tried really hard" part

Comment: Why 5 years? Why not 5 months? Why not 5 weeks? Who decides that term of 5 years trying? You? And what does "really hard" mean? How can one measure "really hard"??